# Assigning null values to SqlParameter DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVolunteers]
(
    [VolID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VolFName] [varchar](20) NULL,

    [DLExpiration] [smalldatetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblVolunteers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([VolID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [uniqueUserID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And I have a stored procedure to update data on this table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[volUpdate]
    @StaffID INT,
    @ModifiedBy VARCHAR(100),
    @NickName VARCHAR(20),
    @FirstName VARCHAR(20), 
    @DLExpiration SMALLDATETIME
AS
    UPDATE tblVolunteers 
    SET
        VolNickName = @NickName, 
        VolFName = @FirstName, 
        DLExpiration = @DLExpiration
    WHERE 
        VolID = @StaffID
```

In some cases I don't have a valid `DLExpiration` to update at that time I want to pass null value to table. And I am doing it like this

```
new SqlParameter("@DLExpiration", null)
```

But still it throws an error

> Procedure or function 'volUpdate' expects parameter '@DLExpiration', which was not supplied.

Can anyone point out What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Could we see some more of your C# code? Just enough to give some context to the creation of your `SqlParameter`.

Comment: How about passing `DBNull.Value` instead of `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `DBNull.Value` to your stored procedure:

```
new SqlParameter("@DLExpiration", DBNull.Value)
```